# Conditionally fill a column using multiple fields using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset where I am looking to see if an ID has switched Jobs as well as Departments through their history and if it happened at least once then create a new column [Transition] that is all 'Yes' or 'No'. Below is the code I have and what it shows:

```
df[Transition] = np.where((df['Job_Code'] != ['Adjusted_Code'] & (df['Department'] != ['Adjusted Department']),'Yes','No')
```

Output:

```
ID  Job_Code  Adjusted_Code   Job_Title  Adjusted_Job  Department Adjusted_Department Transition 
1    327          362         Associate    Manager       Sales         Sales             No
1    327          362         Associate    Manager       Sales         Sales             No
1    362          362         Associate    Manager       Sales         Sales             No
2    358          455         Consult      Advisor       HR            Finance           No
2    455          455         Advisor      Advisor       Finance       Finance           Yes
2    455          455         Advisor      Advisor       Finance       Finance           Yes            
3    215          381         Manager      Director      Tech          Sales             No
3    215          381         Manager      Director      Tech          Sales             No
3    215          381         Manager      Director      Tech          Sales             No
3    381          381         Manager      Director      Sales         Sales             Yes
```

What I want is group by the ID and if Yes is a value at least once then change [Transition] to Yes for all values by ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps. First find the relevant IDs that have atleast one "Yes" condition and then fill in the transition column with Yes or No values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#assuming your dataframe is called df

id_values = df.loc[(df['Job_Code'] != df['Adjusted_Code']) & (df['Department'] != df['Adjusted_Department']), 'ID'].drop_duplicates()
df['Transition'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(id_values), 'Yes', 'No')

df
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to end up with a `Yes` in `Transition` if the corresponding `ID` changed at least once its `Job_Code` and/or its `Department` ?

I would then make use of [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) to count the number of different unique values per `ID` (if there is more than one: there has been a change) for your columns of interest, then affect the `Transition` column respectively:

```
# Use the condition definition that reflects your problem
condition = (df.groupby('ID')['Job_Code'].nunique() > 1) & (df.groupby('ID')['Department'].nunique() > 1)
# condition = (df.groupby('ID')['Job_Code'].nunique() > 1) | (df.groupby('ID')['Department'].nunique() > 1)

# Change the value of Transition for the ID that match the condition
df.loc[condition.loc[df['ID']].values, 'Transition'] = 'Yes'
```

`df` now looks like:

```
   ID  Job_Code  Adjusted_Code  ... Department Adjusted_Department Transition
0   1       327            362  ...      Sales               Sales         No
1   1       327            362  ...      Sales               Sales         No
2   1       362            362  ...      Sales               Sales         No
3   2       358            455  ...         HR             Finance        Yes
4   2       455            455  ...    Finance             Finance        Yes
5   2       455            455  ...    Finance             Finance        Yes
6   3       215            381  ...       Tech               Sales        Yes
7   3       215            381  ...       Tech               Sales        Yes
8   3       215            381  ...       Tech               Sales        Yes
9   3       381            381  ...      Sales               Sales        Yes
```

As a bonus, if the columns starting with `Adjusted_` were created to solve that problem, you can get rid of them, they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75828462/15239951) but using multiple conditions with boolean mask:

```
m1 = df['Job_Code'].ne(df['Adjusted_Code'])
m2 = df['Department'].ne(df['Adjusted_Department'])

df['Transition'] = ((m1&m2).groupby(df['ID']).transform('max')
                           .replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'}))
print(df)

# Output
   ID  Job_Code  Adjusted_Code  Job_Title Adjusted_Job Department Adjusted_Department Transition
0   1       327            362  Associate      Manager      Sales               Sales         No
1   1       327            362  Associate      Manager      Sales               Sales         No
2   1       362            362  Associate      Manager      Sales               Sales         No
3   2       358            455    Consult      Advisor         HR             Finance        Yes
4   2       455            455    Advisor      Advisor    Finance             Finance        Yes
5   2       455            455    Advisor      Advisor    Finance             Finance        Yes
6   3       215            381    Manager     Director       Tech               Sales        Yes
7   3       215            381    Manager     Director       Tech               Sales        Yes
8   3       215            381    Manager     Director       Tech               Sales        Yes
9   3       381            381    Manager     Director      Sales               Sales        Yes
```